# Rails platform: ShareTribe: I want to use Sharetribe open source to create my own application. How can I?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sharetribe

I'm a newbie as Rails, currenty I want to create an application use Sharetribe platform. Can anyone show me how or just give me some documentation about Sharetribe?

Answer (score 3):

Sharetribe has provided a detailed [documentation](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe) for setup. Other than the setup given in the documentation, you will require to install some more things:
Sharetribe uses 'Harmony' for booking process: 
Prerequisites for harmony setup:

1 [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/)

2 [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

3 [lein](https://leiningen.org/)

You can find detailed harmony setup documentation [here](https://github.com/sharetribe/harmony)

Once you complete the above setup, you are good to go for playing with models, controllers and views!

You may find this [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) helpful for MVC.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

They have [pretty detailed docs](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe).  Sharetribe is a fairly complex application, so I recommend starting with Rails tutorials you can find free online - [devcamp](https://rails.devcamp.com/trails/rails-bdd-tdd-course) has some straightforward rails content.

Try to learn as much as you can of the Ruby gems Sharetribe uses as well, as this will help understanding the functionality.